# problem with the fill property of gsap3 the color change is not taking place

Tags: gsap

[image: CODE][I an new to gsap3 and when i tried running this the animation is working fine, but the `fill: "red"`
is not working , the color is not changing at all .]

Comment: Please, add the code as text, not as attached images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fill` property affects SVG elements like `<rect>` and `<path>`. To color a regular DOM element, use `backgroundColor` instead.

Comment: So thats where i was wrong , THANKS for the answer